# How to refresh data in adapter without calling notifyDataSetChanged

Tags: android, gridview, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I'm using recycler view with grid view (every item contains a grid) with thumbnail images after adding images in view it start uploading, and i need to change some values (status) in model at the time of start and finish upload.
What I'm currently doing is change values in model and call notifyDataSetChanged, but it causes to slow down application (hang some times) because it updating every child of list :(
Can any one help me with this?

Comment: All values change or some of the values only?

Comment: @gj at a time one item's value changes from grid.

Comment: there are other methods like notifydatarangeinserted.,notifyItemChanged(int position, Object payload) check the docs http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html/

Comment: Have you tried using notifyItemChanged(int position) instead?

Answer (score 0):

Call notifydatasetchanged() for particular Gridview adapter only. Don't call notifydatasetchanged() for complete recyclerview adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it again to the adapter.

gridview.setAdapter(your adapter) 
-passing your new list to your adapter.

Comment: @nikhil Than It'll not letting me scroll down, keep setting adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `notifyDataSetChanged` updates all of your values regardless if they have a change or not that is why it is slow. I suggest you try using `notifyItemChanged(int position)` instead.

According to [recyclerview docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) this is what `notifyDataSetChanged` does:

> This event does not specify what about the data set has changed, forcing any observers to assume that all existing items and structure may no longer be valid. LayoutManagers will be forced to fully rebind and relayout all visible views.

Comment: I've used notifyItemChanged(int position), but if i use more than 10 images in one grid it call notifyItemChanged 10 times within 1 second so problem remain same.

Comment: Hmmm, how about using observable from rxandroid? I haven't tried it yet but I think it's worth a shot. What will happen is, you will call `notifyItemChanged` all at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but similar to what I'm experiencing.
RecyclerView is usually incredibly fast when changing list details. But manipulating a lot of images can really slow it down if you're not careul.

I'd recommend you try removing the images and repeat it so you can see if that is just as slow. I suspect this will be a lot faster.

If so, make sure you're handling the images off the UI thread. The Android docs recommend you use a library such as Glide which also handles sub-sampling the image to make sure it's the right size.

Hope that helps!